# What are the challenges when doing forensics on cloud storage services?

Tags: forensics, cloud-computing

My class question:

> "What are the key challenges for cloud forensics on cloud storage such
> as Dropbox?"

With what I've been told and what I generally understand, the question is basically what difficulties a digital investigator experiences when trying to perform forensics on cloud storage such as Dropbox.

The papers I've read only mention HOW cloud forensics is done on storage environments such as Dropbox but do not talk about the difficulties. The only closest section in the papers that talk to the challenges is the "limitations" section, which talk about cloud forensics being challenging due to "the server being very big".

Comment: When you find multiple papers on dropbox forensics which don't mention any challenges (didn't read them) ... then maybe it is not challenging? At least not specifically more than in case of other (storage) forensics in the cloud. So there are challenges but those also apply to other cloud storages.

Comment: I think your approach of trying to find a paper that talks about this is not the best approach. This is an exercise in thought, not research. So, think about the different cloud forensic tasks/goals, and consider the challenges of carrying them out on cloud storage services. Besides, we cannot provide references/sources, as I mentioned before.